# Does it make sense to store daily snapshots of data and analysis?

Tags: e-commerce, big-data

I just started working on some data analyzing for an e-commerce site that is moving about 250,000 packages per year. It is very seasonal and need to try to gain insights on both a macro and micro level.

I am just looking for some best practices for how to get started. Should I run a daily script that looks at several key data points and then store them as a snapshot for that day in something like ElasticSearch? Should I just run analysis on demand?

My currently thinking is that data storage is a lot cheaper than data processing and I should analyze a small amount of data each day and store the results in a flat data store to by able to present visually.

Comment: It does if that's what your business requires.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The business side of things doesn't care how it gets done. They just want to see the end results of being able to identify trends and changes in the velocity and probability of different products. I'm just trying to learn some best practices for how others have solved the same/similar problem(s) with the most efficiency.

Comment: Have a look at [OLAP Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube).  But the amount of data you're describing seems small enough where you could just store the data in the database as you receive it, and run your analysis ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this makes sense.

It is common practice, when you have transactional systems with huge databases, to perform analystical reports on a separate business intelligence system.

Depending on the data object and the technical constraints, the common strategies are:

- to replicate data asynchronously (especially with master data taht do not evolve all to often)
- to take snapshots of the new data (especially for huge tables)
- or to take snapshots from the full data object (usually only when something got screwed, or if there is a change in the data structure that requires it)

The aggregation (e.g. daily/weekly/monthly sales figures) is performed accordingly. Note however that the snapshots are usually not a workaround for timestamps on the data, as correction can come in one snapshot, to correct data rollued up in previous snapshots.